# cefsharp WPF app delays closing

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have a WPF project with a cefsharp webbrowser control. The problem is that when I have loaded a page from file (local disk) and i close the app, the window disappears but the app is still running. This is not noticeable when running the exe but when executing from Visual Studio, it takes 30 seconds to a minute before Visual Studio exits running mode. What could the problem be? This also occurs on the WPF minimal example from the project's github by the way.

Comment: You can set a break point on the code that is closing the application.  Then you can uncheck "just my code" in the options window to actually see what's happening (should you feel it's CEF code).  Or you can watch your code to see if the delay is happening there.  Remember that event notification can cause delays as the are synchronous in nature by default.  Ask yourself, are there any eventhandlers waiting on something?  Then prove it via single stepping in the code.

Comment: Unchecked just my code, but when I'm stepping through, it ends at my code, can't step through cefsharp code

Comment: Does the delay happen before you hit breakpoint or afterward?

Comment: @JohnPeters It happens afterwards.

Comment: That pretty much answers you question doesn't it?  There's not much you can do.  Try this bring up a single CEF instance navigate to a site and then tell us how long it takes to close?  This is the most simple and determines if the application load is any factor.  If the times are proportionally similar then you would need to contact the CEF people.